# How to use "WITH" clause with Memgraph’s GQLAlchemy?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

Im working with GQLAlchemy and was wondering how to properly use `WITH` clause and import a CSV file with headers using Memgraph’s GQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example,

```
match().node(variable=“n”).with_({“n”: “node”})….
```

it is with *underscore* method in the query builder and an argument is a dictionary that in the above example means:

```
WITH n AS node
```

Importing CSV files with (or without) headers using **GQLAlchemy** can be done by executing a Cypher query. Check out how the CSV files with a header were imported in our [workshop](https://github.com/memgraph/jupyter-memgraph-tutorials/blob/main/gqlalchemy-workshop/workshop/gqlalchemy-workshop.ipynb).
For example:

```
memgraph.execute(     
"""LOAD CSV FROM "/movies.csv" 
WITH HEADER AS row     
MERGE (m:Movie {id: toInteger(row.movieId), title: row.title})     
WITH m, row     
UNWIND split(row.genres, '|') as genre     
MERGE (m)-[:OF_GENRE]->(:Genre {name: genre});     
""" )
```